# How do I make a chart appear in SSRS?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, charts

I am creating my first ever chart in SSRS.

I have inserted the chart and I can see it (with demo data) in the Design View however, when I preview the report, the chart does not appear. Furthermore, when I save the report and then open it in IE or Firefox, I still cannot see the chart.

The strange thing is, in the SSRS Report Builder, when I click "Print Preview" I can actually see the chart.

If I can see it in Print Preview, obviously, it is generating. How do I view it when I run the report?

Comment: strange, please check may be its rendered on next page; in that case you need to increase the page height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be fixed by restarting the SSRS Service on the server.